# Visible `<br/>` tag in the "Thanks for voting popup"

Tags: bug, user-interface, election

After casting my votes in an election on the network, I had notice popup saying I cast my 3rd vote and thanking me for doing so. However, in the middle of the popup was a visible `<br/>` tag. See below.

[image]

Comment: I put a [simple google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=meta+stack+exchange+%3C%2Fbr%3E+tag+in+tooltip&rlz=1C1CHBF_deDE833DE833&oq=meta+stack+exchange+%3C%2Fbr%3E+tag+in+tooltip&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64l3.39013j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) to find it again ;-)